# how to hide html url, but need to pass the value from URL

Tags: php, html

am using href link, so there is no chance to use post method, now i need to hide the href url,
because am passing a value through it, and taking the value from url in inner page, like example

```
<button onClick="location.href = 'sbsm.php?val=400'">Pay Now</button>
<button onClick="location.href = 'sbsm.php?val=600'">Pay Now</button>
```

now the problem is a user can change the value 400(package1), 600(package2) according to his choice in the URL bar, i want to stop this. How do i prevent this. any suggestion??

---

thanks to all........its working now.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add server-side code in `sbsm.php` that returns an error if the user requests an item that he shouldn't have access to.

In other words, `sbsm.php?val=700` should return an error unless the current user actually has permission to see that.

Comment: I assume you have the products in some sort of db,when the user then enters the site with a val in the url you fetch the product id's/val's from the db and check that the users value is valid

Comment: no buddy actually there is no product der, am selling the service, that why user have to pay according to there package, and there is 6 type of package, value is 400,600,800...etc, now i want to restrict that user to modify the package, as the value is passes over URL. get me? no database no core coding. exactly waht u have edited in last comment.

Comment: @dhruba: So just check how much the user paid in `sbsm.php`.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Apache server try this:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: am trying this on my local server, wampserver

Comment: use .htaccess to redirect the url

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use POST method you can create an html form with action method POST, and a hidden input.

Then write a small function in javascript that updates that field and submits the form.
You can trigger this function via the onClick event.

Comment: can you please make the conversion how it would be like....say this is the button....
<button onClick="location.href = 'sbsm.php?val=400'">Pay Now</button>
how to make it in form tag?

Comment: That does not add _any_ security.

Comment: How to Submit a Form Using JavaScript http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml

Comment: yes! i know dis, dats y am trying to make this change.